# MS Service Fabric for hosting both MVC and services

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Would it be a valid approach to host both frontend (asp.net MVC 6) and backend (WCF/WebAPI services) in MS Service Fabric? Fabric is marketed as a platform for running services. Since both MVC and services need to scale, wouldn't it make sense to have both layers in Service Fabric? Not having to deal with hosting the frontend part separatley, let alone scale it, sounds very compelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I'm not 100% sure you can host an Asp.Net MVC 6 or WCF app inside Service Fabric, but you can certainly host a Web API app. Whatever Asp.Net app you host needs to support OWIN self-hosting, which I'm not totally sure MVC or WCF supports. If you find out that you can host all of those apps, then sure, you should have at it!

I can say that my company's preferred approach is to have a frontend, static application that only serves up static content (HTML, JS) and have that frontend use the Web API we have hosted in Service Fabric. OWIN self-hosting (like what you need to do with Service Fabric), doesn't let you GZip static content without routing it first through a proxy like nginx, and you'll probably want GZip compression with any frontend app. So, you're better off hosting the frontend static application elsewhere, like a traditional Azure Web App that does support GZip compression.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! There was a blog post I think where they showed how one can easily set MVC on OWIN, and host it on SF. So it's definitely doable, just not sure if there are gotchas with this approach :) But like I said, hosting everything in SF cluster shoulds very compelling. An SPA with static contect is definitely an option, and probably wouldn't go inside SF, like you already said

Comment: btw. is the GZip limitation a problem for asp.net mvc too? It includes JQuery, I believe... and therefore serves JS files

Comment: Yep, anything you self-host without IIS (like anything you'd host on SF) *will not be able* to Gzip output. Now, if you run an MVC app in an Azure Web App, you *will be able* to Gzip output because it uses IIS (or some flavor of it). It's just that the OWIN self-host stuff doesn't have that builtin.

Answer (score 0):

I've just created my first Fabric Service app using the latest VS and it allows you create a service as an ASP.Net Core MVC app. Out of the box it uses Kestral as the webserver, but I guess you could use IIS or OWIN as well. If you choose to stick with Kestral, apparently you can add GZip via middleware ([GZip middleware](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1042980/Enabling-GZip-Compression-in-ASP-NET)), although I haven't tried this myself